# Regex help. Lighttpd rewrite rule

Tags: regex, lighttpd

I am not very familiar with Regular expression, but I am asked to modify a lighttpd rewrite rule.

```
url.rewrite = (
    "^/(.+)/?$" => "/index.php/$1"
)
```

I want to exclude a path from the above greedy pattern, so that it won't fall back to *index.php*.

In words, it is simple: Match anything other than "statistics". But I just couldn't get it right in regex.

For example:

- `http://www.foo.com/anything/` → `index.php/anything`
- `http://www.foo.com/statistics/` → `statistics/index.php`

Would you please show me a hint to achieve that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want to use a negative lookahead. Something like

```
"^/(?!statistics)(.+)/?$" => "/index.php/$1"
```

And then you'll need an additional rule for statistics