# RegEx: Not contain specific file types

Tags: regex, lighttpd

I'm searching for a regular expression that hits everything that is NOT ending with `".png"` or `".jpg"`. I want to find out URLs that do not request an image file.

I found something like this: `([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|png))$)` but this is pretty much the opposite of what I want.

Is there an easy way to reverse this? Or is this expression totally wrong?!

Thanx in advance.
Jan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

`([^\s]+(\.(?i)(?!jpg$|png$)[^\s]+)$)`

That expression will match `file.gif` and `file.png2` but not `file.png`.

See also: [Regex help. Lighttpd rewrite rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521989/regex-help-lighttpd-rewrite-rule)