# Redirect all pages but one in Lighttpd

Tags: regex, redirect, lighttpd

How can I redirect all pages but one to HTTPS on my lighttpd web server? I came up with the following, but it still redirects "/report.cgi" - I assume because the second redirect condition overrides the first:

```
# redirect HTTP
server.modules += ( "mod_redirect" )
$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ ".*" {
        url.redirect = (
           "^/report\.cgi$" => "http://%0$0",
           "^/.*$" => "https://%0$0"
        )
    }
}
```

I need this since embedded devices should be able to contact my web server over HTTP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/3522147/3415618, I came up with the following solution:

```
# redirect HTTP
server.modules += ( "mod_redirect" )
$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ ".*" {
        url.redirect = (
            "^/(?!report.cgi).*" => "https://%0$0"
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to solve (letsencrypt webroot authenticator either doesn't follow 301 redirect or getting the temporary challenge files via https).

For some reason the accepted answer didn't work for me, but the following did.

```
$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ ".*" {
        url.redirect = (
            "^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/.*" => "",
            "" => "https://${url.authority}${url.path}${qsa}"
        )
    }
}
```

Found the solution on this page:  https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Mod_redirect

*Redirect rules are evaluated up until the first matched redirect rule. As a special case to allow short-circuiting the redirect rules without triggering a redirect, specify a blank target: url.redirect = ( "^/do-not-redirect/this/path" => "" ). Then, a further catch-all redirect rule might redirect everything else. This can be used as an alternative to nested conditions inside other conditions. The blank target special-case is available in version 1.4.40 or later.*

Comment: This is the cleaner solution.  Also, given the mod_redirect extended patterns used in the substitution, the condition `$HTTP["host"] =~ ".*"` is not necessary, though what is inside the block `{ ... }` is still needed (without the '{' and '}'.